# What are driving factors behind the recent slew of layoffs in the US tech industry (to the extent we understand them)?

Tags: technology, labour-economics

Is this phenomenon something that economists think they have an understanding of? As an outsider, I'm very confused. The tech industry seems to be making a lot of money right now. Why is all of this profit resulting in fewer job opportunities for workers? Thanks.

Comment: I forecast that instead of writing "managers overestimated their demand for labour after the pandemic, and while they could be profitable without layoffs, they can be **more** profitable with layoffs" someone will write about 'AI' tools such as MS Copilot boosting productivity and make a classical supply shift argument without any supporting data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason(in simple terms) is that tech companies, even large ones, have a lot of future growth priced into them. As intertest rates rose to combat inflation, these kinds of speculative future investments became less profitable, and the industry had less investment behind it.